# User-based vs Clustering-based Collaborative Filtering

Tags: self-study, k-nearest-neighbour, recommender-system

Reading about recommender systems in this [blog](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/recommender-systems-with-python-part-ii-collaborative-filtering-k-nearest-neighbors-algorithm-c8dcd5fd89b2), i found that KNN (k-nearest neighbors) can be used for user-item (user-based) collaborative filtering to find similar users. But in another category of collaborative filtering approaches, namely model-based, there is a clustering based approach which also can use KNN (as shown in figure below):

[image]

**So i have two questions:**

1. I searched a lot but i couldn't find out what is the difference between a *"user-based approach using KNN"* with a *"clustering based approach using KNN"*?
2. Although KNN is a classification algorithm, it's being used in user-based collaborative filtering without doing any sort of classification. Given an item as input, it's just used to find top $k$ items, having minimum distance to the input item. So why use KNN without any classification?